# Azure WebApp Docker Compose Private Repository

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-service

With the Azure [WebApp Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-create) I can deploy a docker-compose file to Azure easily with public available docker images. I would like to know how it is possible to deploy an image hosted in a private repository respectively in Azure Container Service to Azure WebApp Service.

Comment: Here is the corresponding Github Issue for this topic: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9685

Answer (score 3):

You can provide the following variables in the App Service's app settings to pull from a private registry: `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME`, `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD`, `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL`

Comment: Exactly, but it is `docker-registry-server-user`, not `docker-registry-server-username`. It seems to be the same process as for loading docker container from ACR. Unfortunately it is not good described in the existing Microsoft docs, but meanwhile I know that people are already working on this.